# Redirecting eMail from a particular address to a separate inbox

Tags: exchange

Is there a way to set up an Exchange server so that any eMail sent to it from a particular address gets redirected from the address it's getting sent to, to a separate inbox instead.  For example:

exchange domain is @company.com
There is eMail coming in from johndoe@example.com to multiple accounts @company.com.

How do I make it so that all eMail from johndoe@example.com, no matter what @company.com account the eMail is addressed to, it won't go to the address it's trying to send to, but will go to overflow@company.com only instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't said which version of Exchange, but as long as it is 2007 or higher then a transport rules will do this. The rule will be pretty straight forward using the wizard.

Comment: Thanks.  I'm brand new to my job, and this is something we didn't cover in school.  My boss tasked me with researching how to do this, and I had no real idea where to start.  This helps a lot.